# jq: Group by nested structures and flatten JSON

Tags: json, jq

I'm new to jq and command line tools in general, but I need to group by nested structures in a JSON file and flatten the nested structures, and I've not been able to find a workable solution for a few days, here's a sample of my JSON.

```
[
  {
    "Value1": "0",
    "Conversions": "0",
    "Revenue": "0.00",
    "serverTimestamp": 84615198,
    "pluginsIcons": [
      {
        "pluginName": "pdf",
        "pluginIcon": "pdf1"
      },
      {
        "pluginName": "java",
        "pluginIcon": "java1"
      }
    ],
    "plugins": "pdf, java",
    "customVariables": {
      "3": {
        "customVariableValue3": "F",
        "customVariableName3": "Gender"
      },
      "2": {
        "customVariableValue2": "Person",
        "customVariableName2": "Role"
      },
      "1": {
        "customVariableValue1": "Partner1",
        "customVariableName1": "Partner"
      }
    },
    "interactions": "7",
    "actions": "3",
    "actionDetails": [
      {
        "timestamp": 84615195,
        "interactionPosition": "1",
        "type": "action"
      },
      {
        "timestamp": 84615145,
        "interactionPosition": "2",
        "type": "action"
      },
      {
        "timestamp": 84615693,
        "interactionPosition": "3",
        "type": "action",
        "customVariables": {
          "2": {
            "customVariablePageValue2": "value2",
            "customVariablePageName2": "name2"
          },
          "1": {
            "customVariablePageValue1": "value1",
            "customVariablePageName1": "name1"
          }
        }
      }
    ],
    "operatingSystem": "Windows 10"
  },
  {
    "Value1": "18",
    "Conversions": "1",
    "Revenue": "0.00",
    "serverTimestamp": 84615189,
    "pluginsIcons": [
      {
        "pluginName": "pdf",
        "pluginIcon": "pdf1"
      }
    ],
    "plugins": "pdf",
    "customVariables": {
      "3": {
        "customVariableValue3": "M",
        "customVariableName3": "Gender"
      },
      "2": {
        "customVariableValue2": "Admin",
        "customVariableName2": "Role"
     },
      "1": {
        "customVariableValue1": "Place",
        "customVariableName1": "Subdomain"
      }
    },
    "interactions": "6",
    "actions": "3",
    "actionDetails": [
      {
        "timestamp": 84635189,
        "timeSpent": "11",
        "interactionPosition": "1",
        "type": "action"
      },
      {
        "timestamp": 846351834,
        "timeSpent": "11",
        "interactionPosition": "2",
        "type": "search"
      },
      {
        "timestamp": 846351832,
        "timeSpent": "1",
        "interactionPosition": "3",
        "type": "action",
        "customVariables": {
          "2": {
            "customVariablePageValue2": "value2",
            "customVariablePageName2": "name2"
          },
          "1": {
            "customVariablePageValue3": "value3",
            "customVariablePageName3": "name3"
          }
        },
        "generationTime": "890"
      }
    ],
    "operatingSystem": "Windows 10"
  }
]
```

The way it should look at the end result would be with one flattened entry for each "action" in the nested arrays under "actionDetails"

I have been able to flatten the structures, but then grouping by (and duplicating the other columns for each action) becomes convoluted.  Grouping by the "action"s before flattening has not worked for me because they're nested.

An example of how the first entry in the original JSON should look afterwards is:

```
[
  {
    "timestamp": 84615195,
    "interactionPosition": "1",
    "type": "action",
    "Value1": "0",
    "Conversions": "0",
    "Revenue": "0.00",
    "pluginName1": "pdf",
    "pluginIcon1": "pdf",
    "pluginName2": "java",
    "pluginIcon2": "java",
    "plugins": "pdf, java",
    "Gender": "F",
    "Role": "Person",
    "Partner": "Partner1",
    "interactions": "7",
    "actions": "3",
    "operatingSystem": "Windows 10"
  },
  {
    "timestamp": 84615145,
    "interactionPosition": "2",
    "type": "action",
    "Value1": "0",
    "Conversions": "0",
    "Revenue": "0.00",
    "pluginName1": "pdf",
    "pluginIcon1": "pdf",
    "pluginName2": "java",
    "pluginIcon2": "java",
    "plugins": "pdf, java",
    "Gender": "F",
    "Role": "Person",
    "Partner": "Partner1",
    "interactions": "7",
    "actions": "3",
    "operatingSystem": "Windows 10"
  },
  {
    "timestamp": 84615693,
    "interactionPosition": "3",
    "type": "action",
    "Value1": "0",
    "Conversions": "0",
    "Revenue": "0.00",
    "pluginName1": "pdf",
    "pluginIcon1": "pdf",
    "pluginName2": "java",
    "pluginIcon2": "java",
    "plugins": "pdf, java",
    "Gender": "F",
    "Role": "Person",
    "Partner": "Partner1",
    "interactions": "7",
    "actions": "3",
    "operatingSystem": "Windows 10",
    "name1": "value1",
    "name2": "value2"
   }
]
```

You may note in the above that some of the flattened key names have been replaced by an associated value (inside the same nested structure).  This isn't completely necessary, but it would be a nice bonus.  Also worth noting:  My JSON is large (800MB), and I would like to do that, but I suppose that point would be best posed in another question.

Thanks in advance for any assistance or advice!

Comment: You can use something like this : `map(. as $parent | .actionDetails | map({ timestamp, interactionPosition, type, Value1:$parent.Value1, Conversions:$parent.Conversions }))`

Comment: @peak I'm not sure i completely understand what you mean.  I omitted brackets on the outside of the code snippet but assumed that this would be implied.  Otherwise, the formatting fits that of a flattened json

Comment: Your edit resolves the matter so I've deleted the comment. For future reference, in case you haven't read the relevant guidelines, please see [mcve].

Comment: @Aaron This actually worked as a simple start... the command gets relatively absurd given the number of columns, but it works in the end and accomplishes the grouping aspect better than any other solution I've tried.  Thank you!

Comment: If there is any way to edit @Aaron 's command to include all $parent fields without individually specifying them, it would help me tremendously.

Answer (score 0):

The following answer does not deal with every requirement you've mentioned
but it will hopefully get you over the main hurdle you've evidently been facing.

Since your requirements regarding the "customVariables" are not clear to me,
I'll ignore .customVariables completely, and hopefully you'll also
be able to handle .pluginsIcons yourself once you're over the main hurdle.
So for clarity, I'll simply delete those keys.

As I understand it, you want some grouping to take place after the flattening based
on .actionDetails.  These requirements are also unclear to me so let's
focus on the flattening:

```
.[]
| .actionDetails[] + (del(.actionDetails) | del(.customVariables) | del(.pluginsIcons))
```

This produces a stream of JSON objects, the first two of which are:

```
{
  "timestamp": 84615195,
  "interactionPosition": "1",
  "type": "action",
  "Value1": "0",
  "Conversions": "0",
  "Revenue": "0.00",
  "serverTimestamp": 84615198,
  "plugins": "pdf, java",
  "interactions": "7",
  "actions": "3",
  "operatingSystem": "Windows 10"
}
{
  "timestamp": 84615145,
  "interactionPosition": "2",
  "type": "action",
  "Value1": "0",
  "Conversions": "0",
  "Revenue": "0.00",
  "serverTimestamp": 84615198,
  "plugins": "pdf, java",
  "interactions": "7",
  "actions": "3",
  "operatingSystem": "Windows 10"
}
```

This is very similar to the expected output you've shown, so hopefully you can take it from here.

Comment: I've received multiple compile errors from the direct jq command and smaller variations of it, unfortunately I wasn't able to make a workable solution out of this.

Comment: I've verified it works (jq -f program.jq input.json) using jq 1.3, jq 1.4, jq 1.5 and jq 1.6.

Comment: You're correct, thanks for your response!  You are correct in that it clears the main hurdle of my challenge, I'll try to handle renaming and restructuring the customVariables.